# Is it possible to use ES6 base classes with node modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

Consider a node module (superModule) which is extendible by way of plugins; it seems reasonable that such a plugin could be implemented like shown below:

```
const superModule = require("super-module");

class SpecialPlugin extends superModule.Plugin {
    foo() {
    }
}

module.exports = SpecialPlugin;
```

This means that a project using both the "super-module" and the "super-module-special-plugin" modules would look something like follows:

```
{project}/
  |-node_modules/
  |   |-super-module/                 <----
  |   |   |-index.js                      |
  |   |   |-package.json                  |
  |   |                                   |-- Included Twice?!
  |   |-super-module-special-plugin/      |
  |   |   |-node_modules/                 |
  |   |   |   |-super-module/         <----
  |   |   |   |   |-index.js
  |   |   |   |   |-package.json
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |-index.js
  |   |   |-package.json
  |   |
  |-index.js
  |-package.json
```

The directory structure contains the same "super-module" implementation twice.

Q1. How does NPM behave in this scenario?

Q2. Is it simply not possible to expose a base "Plugin" class?

**Update / Afterthought:**

Or perhaps the right approach would be to do something like follows whereby the "super-module" is injected into its plugin by the caller.

```
module.exports.setup = function(superModule) {
    return class SuperPlugin extends superModule.Plugin {
        foo() {
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does NPM behave in this scenario?

Depends on the version. npm@3 flattens all dependencies if possible. So if both packages refer to the same version, `super-module` will only be included once. If there is a version conflict, `super-module-special-plugin` will install it's own copy just like in your example.

npm@2 does not dedupe by default, so in that case it will store two copies of the same module.

> Is it simply not possible to expose a base "Plugin" class?

Sure it is. Injecting the base class as dependency is valid and not uncommon approach.

`super-module-special-plugin` could also declare `super-module` as a [*peer dependency*](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/). In that case it is the responsibility of the "parent" package to provide `super-module`. Peer dependencies had be designed with this use case in mind.

Peer dependency handling changed a bit from npm@2 to npm@3. npm@2 would always install the peer dependency if it was not already present. npm@3 doesn't do that anymore, so you have to explicitly install it.

Comment: **Aside:** I found that I had to update to the latest npm in order for the peer dependencies to work correctly.